# sorting an associative array without losing your indexes

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I have the following array:

```
packages    Array (@24ff99c1)   
                [99767] Array (@24ff9809)   
                    forceUpload false   
                    length  0   
                    name    "testdocument.indd" 
                    packageId   "99767" 
                    progressStatus  "allowed"   
                    singleItemSize  50582294 [0x303d316]    
                    singleItemUploadedSoFar 17296352 [0x107ebe0]    
                    sortIndex   1338984578952 [0x137c1b33f88]   
                    status  "upload busy"   
                    totalSize   431203849 [0x19b3a609]  
                    uploadedAtm "37015918"  
                    uploadedSoFar   "19719566"  
                [94854] Array (@24ff7fd9)   
                    forceUpload false   
                    length  0   
                    name    "testdocument.indd" 
                    packageId   "16842" 
                    progressStatus  "allowed"   
                    singleItemSize  6344704 [0x60d000]  
                    singleItemUploadedSoFar 6344704 [0x60d000]  
                    sortIndex   1338984606428 [0x137c1b3aadc]   
                    status  "upload busy"   
                    totalSize   862407698 [0x33674c12]  
                    uploadedAtm "6344704"   
                    uploadedSoFar   ""  
                length  2
```

Now i want to sort it according to the sortIndex.I tried this like that:

```
packageData.data.packages.sortOn("sortIndex");
```

It is sorted but the problem is that my indexes get changed to 0, 1, 2, ... like the following:

```
packages    Array (@24ff99c1)   
                [0] Array (@24ff9809)   
                    forceUpload false   
                    length  0   
                    name    "testdocument.indd" 
                    packageId   "99767" 
                    progressStatus  "allowed"   
                    singleItemSize  50582294 [0x303d316]    
                    singleItemUploadedSoFar 17296352 [0x107ebe0]    
                    sortIndex   1338984578952 [0x137c1b33f88]   
                    status  "upload busy"   
                    totalSize   431203849 [0x19b3a609]  
                    uploadedAtm "37015918"  
                    uploadedSoFar   "19719566"  
                [1] Array (@24ff7fd9)   
                    forceUpload false   
                    length  0   
                    name    "testdocument.indd" 
                    packageId   "16842" 
                    progressStatus  "allowed"   
                    singleItemSize  6344704 [0x60d000]  
                    singleItemUploadedSoFar 6344704 [0x60d000]  
                    sortIndex   1338984606428 [0x137c1b3aadc]   
                    status  "upload busy"   
                    totalSize   862407698 [0x33674c12]  
                    uploadedAtm "6344704"   
                    uploadedSoFar   ""  
                length  2
```

How can is sort the array without losing the indexes?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is your array keys are ints.
Because they are int it is acting as a regular array and not an associative array.
When you do packages[99767] you are looking at the element at index 99767.
By sorting the array it will begin your index's at 0.
What you need to change is the keys convert them to strings.

Answer (score 1):

You cant. Sort changes the order of the array. Only option you have is to add an array item containing the index you would like it to have.

Comment: I know the sort changes, i dont mind that, but i dont want the indexes to change. atm the indexes change, in this case, from 99767to 0 and from 94854 to 1, i just want them to keep the original indexes -> 99767 and 94854.

Comment: As far as I know your choices are as follows: 1-Sort and have the indexes change; 2-Dont sort. If you need the sort, the only thing I can recommend is what I said above. At something to the array to identify its original position.